# Do I need down-specific washing liquid for my coat?

Tags: clothing, cleaning

I bought some nikwax Down Wash to wash my sudden coat.

Out of interest I compared it to a bottle of Nikwax Tech Wash. They appear to contain identical ingredients :

> contains among over ingredients less than 5% polycarboxylates. 5-15% soap. Non-ionic suficactants.

So given that, I already own a big bottle of tech wash, I can't see a good reason to buy down specific wash, they appear to be identical.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 6):

There's no way you can know from that description whether the two products are identical. There's more than one kind of polycarboxylate, more than one kind of soap, more than one kind of non-ionic surfactant, and certainly more than one kind of ‘other ingredient’. Even if some of those ingredients are the same, their concentrations may be different. Of course it *might* be that the two products just the same thing in different bottles, but without an inside contact at Nikwax or some expensive lab work, it's going to be hard to find out for sure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the legislation is that they have to list all "active" ingredients, no? So any other ingredients don't affect how it works. It is interesting that their are multiple types of the active ingredients though.

Comment: It is also possible that even though the ingredients are the same, the instructions on how to wash the garment or down product is different on the label depending on whether it is Tech Wash (for non-down clothing) or Down Wash (for down clothing). I have heard of this being the case for Grangers products.